# Django UnboundLocalError local variable 'enroll' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

My code is of an enrolment list for a student. It shows subjects a student can enroll and ones the student already has enrolled and can tick as passed, delete or unpass the passed ones. The problem is when I want to add/enroll a new subject I get the following error.  If someone can take a look and help, much appreciated.

TRACEBACK

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/enrolment/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'App',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\project\App\decorations.py", line 15, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\project\App\views.py", line 73, in enrolment_view
    enroll(request.POST.get('enroll'),student)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /enrolment/
Exception Value: local variable 'enroll' referenced before assignment
```

MY VIEW

```
def enroll(subject_id, student):
    if not Enrolment.objects.filter(student_id_id=student.id, predmet_id_id=subject_id):
        Enrolment.objects.create(student_id_id=student.id, predmet_id_id=subject_id, status='enrolled')

def delete(subject_id, student):
    Enrolment.objects.filter(predmet_id_id=subject_id, student_id_id=student.id).delete()

def passed(subject_id, student):
    Enrolment.objects.filter(predmet_id_id=subject_id, student_id_id=student.id).update(status='passed')

def not_passed(subject_id, student):
    Enrolment.objects.filter(predmet_id_id=subject_id, student_id_id=student.id).delete()

@student_required
def enrolment_view(request):
    if (request.user.is_authenticated):
        username = request.user.get_username()
        student = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            if request.POST.get('enroll'):
                enroll(request.POST.get('enroll'),student)
            elif request.POST.get('delete'):
                delete(request.POST.get('delete'),student)
            elif request.POST.get('passed'):
                passed(request.POST.get('passed'),student)
            elif request.POST.get('not_passed'):
                not_passed(request.POST.get('not_passed'),student)
    
        enroll = Enrolment.objects.filter(student_id_id=student.id).order_by('predmet_id')
        subjects = Subject.objects.exclude(id__in=enroll.values('predmet_id'))
        subj_all = Subject.objects.all()
        if student.status == 'REDOVNI':
            br_sem = 6
        else:
            br_sem = 8
        context = {
            'subjects':subjects,
            'enroll':enroll,
            'student':student,
            'semestar':range(1, br_sem + 1),
            'all':subj_all
        }
        return render(request, 'enrolment.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect ('login')
```

MY TEMPLATE

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Upisni list</h1>
<div class='row'>
    <div class = 'border col-md-6 flrx-column'>
        <h1>Predmeti</h1>
        {% for subj in subjects %}
        <form method = 'POST'>{% csrf_token %}
            <button type='submit' name='enroll' value="{{subj.id}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark">+</button>
            {{subj.kod}} {{subj.ime}}
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class = 'border col-md-5 flrx-column'>
        <h1>Student {{student.username}} predmeti</h1>
        {% for sem in semestar %}
        <div class = 'border'>
            <h3>Semestar {{sem}}</h3>
            {% for subject in all %}
            {% for enrl in enroll %}
            {% if subject.id == enrl.predmet_id_id %}
            {% if student.status == "REDOVNI" and subject.sem_redovni == sem %}
            <form method = 'POST' class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">{% csrf_token %}
                {{subject.kod}}{{subject.ime}}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    {% if enrl.status == 'enrolled' %}
                    <button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark">x</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="passed" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark"> &#10004;</button>
                    {% elif enrl.status == 'passed' %}
                    <span>   &#10004;</span>
                    <button type="submit" name="not_passed" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark"> Unpass</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </form>
            {% elif student.status == "IZVANREDNI" and subject.sem_izvanredni == sem %}
            <form method = 'POST' class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">{% csrf_token %}
                {{subject.kod}}{{subject.ime}}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    {% if enrl.status == 'enrolled' %}
                    <button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark">x</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="passed" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark"> &#10004;</button>
                    {% elif enrl.status == 'passed' %}
                    <span>   &#10004;</span>
                    <button type="submit" name="not_passed" value="{{subject.id}}"class="btn btn-outline-dark"> Unpass</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is enroll function defined, did you import it ?  Also you seem to be reusing a lot of variables with same name which might lead to shadowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling function enroll, before it is known:

```
if request.POST.get('enroll'):
    enroll(request.POST.get('enroll'),student)
```

Comment: my bad I forgot to include the definition of the function. I edited it.

Comment: you have function enroll, and variable enroll - that is the problem

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.